# Sanity: Custom component in array change to custom component space

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, sanity

I am trying to implement a custom component in array of strings field. I am able to implement it, but it is taking row per component. Whereas my component is quite small.

**Current Output:**

[image]

**Schema**

```
defineField({
      name: "colors",
      title: "Colors",
      type: "array",
      of: [
        defineField({
          name: "color",
          type: "string",
          components: {
            input: ColorSelector,
          },
        }),
      ],
      options: {
        layout: "grid",
      },
    }),
```

**Custom Component**

```
import { ColorPicker } from "antd";
import { Color } from "antd/es/color-picker";
import { useCallback } from "react";
import { set, unset } from "sanity";

const ColorSelector = (props: any) => {
  const { onChange } = props;

  const handleChange = useCallback(
    (value: Color, hex: string) => {
      onChange(hex ? set(hex) : unset());
    },
    [onChange]
  );

  return <ColorPicker onChange={handleChange} allowClear size="large" />;
};

export default ColorSelector;
```

**I want similar to this Output:**[image]